# Bootstrap Validator is not turning all form labels red

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have set up [Boostrap Validator](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/#) to work with my forms but I'm getting an issue where it does not make the label on some types of input red (when there is an error). I've attached a JSFiddle of what I mean.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sinesine/5zqjjcmm/)

As you can see, the normal input is fine and the label turns red as well the outline of the box, but with the data-list example, the label is not turning red.

Apologies for the tags, I wasn't sure if this was a CSS issue or not so I've included all the languages I'm using to do this.

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
(It won't let me post without code)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some CSS on the data list label.  You need the `"control-label"` class as below:

```
 <label for="flightnature" class="control-label">Data list input:</label>
```

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the class for first label

class="control-label "

Good luck